# Android resizing of ImageView causes the resizing of the View container

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, layoutparams

In my app I have a ListView with an ImageView in each row of the list. This ImageView is populated with images from web. When I download the first image, I calculate the height of the bitmap because I have to set the height of the list items in accordance with the height of this bitmap. I don't have a place holder, so I choose this approach to avoid expanding each list item when the image is populated.

The issue I am facing is when I try to resize the ImageView, actually what is resized it the entire view group, LinearLayout in this case.

Here is some code:

*List item layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*Method that do the resizing:*

```
private void resizeImageContainer(ViewHolder viewHolder, int height) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
    viewHolder.photo.setLayoutParams(imageLayoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to chagne it size like this : vievHolder.photo.getLayoutParams().height = height;  vievHolder.photo.requestLayout(), just to be sure that method is not a problem here

Comment: Try wrapping the imageView inside another LinearLayout. Adapters dont do a good job at keeping the right params of the parent without nested LInearLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering why you are choosing to use a LinearLayout to create a list instead of using a ListView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) I've used them before and they are a lot more reliable in creating lists where you're not sure how many items will be in the list. When using ListView, you can also customize the exact size of each row so that you don't have to alter the row size dynamically for each element.

Also, judging from your description, it seems you want to place an image to the side of a Textview. If that's the case, I stumbled onto this myself previously and you can actually do that without using an ImageView.
See the following link for more details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft